# How do you parse a message from Sendgrid using their Parse API with Django?

Tags: python, django, parsing, sendgrid

SendGrid can parse the attachments and contents from incoming emails. Application examples include receiving uploads and posting blog articles via email.

The parse API will POST the parsed email to a URL configured in your account. SendGrid automatically queues and retries any POSTs that respond with a 5XX status error.

- http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/parse-api-2/

Answer (score 4):

Looks pretty simple to me.

```
class Attachment(Model):
    file = FileField()

class Email(Model):
    headers = TextField()
    text = TextField()
    html = TextField()
    to = TextField()
    cc = TextField()
    subject = TextField()
    dkim = JSONField()
    SPF = JSONField()
    envelope = JSONField()
    charsets = CharField(max_length=255)
    spam_score = FloatField()
    spam_report = TextField()
    attachments = ManyToManyField(Attachment) 

EmailForm(ModelForm)
    attachments = IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Email
        exclude = 'attachments'

@requires_POST
def sendgrid_email_reciever(request):
    form = EmailForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid()
        form.instance.save()
        for i in range(1,form.cleaned_data.['attachments']+1):
            attachment = request.FILES['attachment%d' % i]
            form.instance.attachments.create(file=attachment.read())
```